# What laws/regulations/statutes must LexisNexis follow regarding opt-out privileges of certain groups

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, privacy

One can go to [LexisNexis](https://optout.lexisnexis.com/) to suppress information.
There are several options on why you want your information suppressed, but three stood-out:

- I am a public/elected Official
- I am a law enforcement officer
- I am a judicial officer

What federal laws regulate LexisNexis handling of these members' information?

Comment: I'd guess that a law mandating an opt-out option would violate the First Amendment freedom of the press.  This might just be a policy that LexisNexis created voluntarily.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of suppressing information is to suppress information that would make "doxxing" inaccessible. Doxxing is the sharing of personal contact and address information about people without their consent, generally with an intent that the people with whom the information was shared with protest, stalk, or harm the individual doxed.

One category not listed in the OP under U.S. federal law is [18 U.S. Code § 119](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/119) (enacted in 2008) which prohibits sharing certain information about jurors and certain witnesses in certain kinds of cases.

Multiple states have passed or considered passing similar laws, including [Colorado](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/05/19/us/colorado-doxxing-law.html), some of which have been challenged in court (such as [a Washington State law that was blocked by a judge](https://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/federal-judge-blocks-washington-state-cyberstalking-law/) as potentially unconstitutional). According to the New York Times, as of May 19, 2021:

> Doxxing is not a federal crime, although federal laws related to
> stalking and conspiracy can apply to the practice. Colorado is one of
> several states to take steps to make doxxing a crime.
>
> Gov. Kevin Stitt of Oklahoma signed a bill last month prohibiting the
> doxxing of law enforcement officers. A similar measure signed into law
> last year in New Jersey also protects judges and prosecutors.

The limited legal remedies available under current law are reviewed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxing).

Legislation is pending in several other states.

The [Public Service Protection Act of 2020](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/116/s4965) was introduced but did not become law.